# Using PointCloud in AMCL

Tags: navigation, amcl, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using the AMCL filter from ROS packages and I have configured it following the instructions on the website.
I am wondering if it is possible to change the sensor input from the laser to a pointcloud without using any other package.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196010/using-pointcloud-in-amcl/) by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 223 on 2014-10-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know you said "without using any other package" but the common way to acheive what you're asking about is to input your point cloud in the [pointcloud_to_laserscan](http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan) node, which will output a laser scan that you can feed into AMCL without problems.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2014-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on 2014-10-27**:
I've tried it, but I am using ROS Hydro and I haven't been able to build that package and use it.

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2014-10-27**:
Oh I see. I think the best way to acheive your goal is to focus on using that package though rather than searching for an alternative.

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-10-27**:
pointcloud_to_laserscan was added to hydro and indigo very recently, so it hasn't gone through the process of being fully released yet (so you won't be able to grab it via apt-get). It had been replaced by depthimage_to_lasrscan in groovy, but clearly there's some use for it yet!

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-10-27**:
For now please build from [source](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/tree/indigo-devel/pointcloud_to_laserscan), and make sure to open an issue on github if you have any problems, since it underwent a bit of a rewrite. Check the launch files for usage examples.

**Comment by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on 2014-10-29**:
thank you.
I am new in programming and I didn't know about the possibility of issuing in github.